# How to create simple parallax on scroll using HTML + CSS + JS (limited)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

The problem I had was to create a **simple parallax effect** on a body without any extra HTML elements.

The setup: `<body>` with fixed background image and background-size:cover;. All direct children of body have background color, but `<header>` which is used to show the body background picture.

! If you plan on using `background-size:cover;`, then `position:sticky;` bar at top is a must.

For illustrative purpose:

```
<body>
<nav style='background: white;height:160px;position:sticky;top:0px;'></nav>
<header id='see_through'>This works as the "window" for body background picture</header>
<main style='background: white;'></main>
<footer style='background: white;'></footer>
</body>
```

Current CSS code:

```
body {
background:url('header-background.jpg');
background-position:center bottom;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
}
```

All examples I could find on Google or Stackoverflow involved using some library (mainly jQuery) or some extensive code and/or extra HTML elements.

The main perquisite I had is - no HTML changes and no libraries if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Solution involves adding an eventListener for scroll event.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    scroll_position = window.scrollY; /* Current scroll position */
    header_height = document.getElementById('see_through').clientHeight; /* header height */
    /* Parallax height can't be more than sticky bars' height, applies only when using background-size:cover; */
    parallax_height_max = 160;
    if(scroll_position > header_height){ /* if scroll position is past header, basically ignore */
        position = 0;
    }else{
        position = parallax_height_max - Math.floor(scroll_position / header_height * parallax_height_max); /* calculate relative position of background image */
    }
    /* set new background vertical position, this can be moved to ELSE part, depending on your requirements */
    document.body.style.setProperty('background-position-y', position + 'px');
});
```

And CSS addition includes:

```
body {
transition:background-position ease-in-out; /* optional */
background-position-y:160px; /* initial position */
}
```

So the whole effect is based on having one transparent element with opaque element before and after, but should be adjustable in different scenarios (fixed element size, windows borders).

The Javascript part cleaned-up/minimilised (removed parts, less dynamic):

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    header_height = document.getElementById('see_through').clientHeight;
    if(window.scrollY < header_height){
        document.body.style.setProperty('background-position-y', (160 - Math.floor(window.scrollY / header_height * 160)) + 'px');
    }
});
```

I hope this helps.